# Why aren't default parameters for functions respected when called via Selector in Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime

Methods called via Selector don't respect default parameter values.

**EXAMPLE**

If I have a button wired up to call a function via a selector:

```
func setupButton() {
    self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(printValue), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func printValue(value:Int = 7)
{
    if value == 7 {
       print("received default")
    } else {
       print("default unused")
    }
}
```

When calling this method via code *"received default"* is printed, but when I press the button and call the method via selector *"default unused"* is printed because 7 wasn't set as the value.

---

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default parameters are *inserted* by the Swift compiler when you call the function.
So this is a **compile-time** thing.

When manually calling the function via a selector, you use the Objective-C runtime, which has no idea about your default parameters.
This is a **runtime thing**.

Moreover, default parameters don't exist in Objective-C.

You can think of Swift default parameters as a compile-time convenience.
But once you run your code, they're basically gone.

**EDIT**

If you're looking for a workaround, I can suggest having two different functions, without using default parameters:

```
@objc func printValue()
{
    printValue(value: 7)
}

@objc func printValue(value:Int)
{}
```

This way, you can call it without arguments through the Objective-C runtime.
Note that when using `#selector`, you'll need to cast to resolve ambiguity:

```
self.button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector((printValue as () -> Void)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anywhere that other quirks like this (conflicts between expected behaviour in swift and the obj-c runtime's abilities) would be documented?

Comment: @DanCarlson I not aware of such a documentation unfortunately. Also see the edit if you're looking for a workaround.

Comment: In the interests of learning, is there an obvious reason your suggested 'workaround' isn't done by the swift compiler automatically in this case?  i.e. if a method has a default parameter value, couldn't the complier spoof the name of that function onto a wrapper function that inserted the default values before calling the original function?

Comment: @DanCarlson That's probably asking too much for the Swift compiler. It cannot really detect how you will use the selector. In your example, you don't get the expected behavior, but you could also have used the same selector with an `NSInvocation`, passing the required arguments yourself. And that would be fine. Also I think creating the "wrapper" function automatically could lead to unwanted side effects.